# How does matlab generate Gaussian distributed random numbers?

Tags: c, matlab, random, distribution, gaussian

I need to create matrix of Gaussian distributed random numbers in C. I was curious how does matlab generates it so that I can take a lead from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate Normal random numbers, the C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

double drand()   /* uniform distribution, (0..1] */
{
  return (rand()+1.0)/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
}

double random_normal() 
 /* normal distribution, centered on 0, std dev 1 */
{
  return sqrt(-2*log(drand())) * cos(2*M_PI*drand());
}
```

if I want to create a random variable with mean 1 and std of 0.5 then,

```
int main()
{

  int i;
  double rands[1000];
  for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
  rands[i] = 1.0 + 0.5*random_normal();
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to learn, have a look at [this](http://www.design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/Gaussian.html). 
The most common practical methods are [Box-Muller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) or [Marsaglia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method).

Then have a look at [this](http://c-faq.com/lib/gaussian.html).

IMO you should use a proper random generator, typically [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), for which you can find implementations [here](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html).

Finally, of course if you have the choice to go with C++, use the C++11 [random library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Comment: But how to generate Gaussian distribution from here? I don't know exactly but looks like this gives only uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

[Matlab uses](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97811-what-is-the-algorithm-used-by-the-normally-distributed-pseudorandom-number-generator-randn-in-matlab) a variant of the [ziggurat algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm).  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution) for other techniques you could use.  The Box-Muller method mentioned in other answers is relatively easy to understand and implement, but is slower than the ziggurat algorithm and also suffers from an interaction with [Linear Congruential Generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) which causes generated values to all [fall along spirals](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/hinow/www/workshop_97.pdf).